# Нужна ли запятая перед "то" в обороте "то что"?

Tags: пунктуация

Помимо чеков, понадобятся дорожные документы, бумаги, подтверждающие оприходование на складе то, что эти товары были использованы вами при производстве этой продукции.

Comment: Оприходование на складе то?

Comment: Поставьте вместо "проблемной" запятой союз "и" (подтверждающие А **и** Б).